# How can I set useState with an array of dataresults from the database?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

Compiles ok but Getting undefined in state.  Appreciate any advice!

```
customer_data = customer_data?.listCustomers[0];

console.log(customer_data?.sunday_open);  /// returns 08:00:00
const [accountInfo, setAccountInfo] = useState({ "sunday_open_hours": customer_data?.sunday_open.split(":")[0], 
"sunday_open_mins" : customer_data?.sunday_open.split(":")[1]});
console.log(accountInfo)
```

this code:

```
console.log(accountInfo)
```

returns:

```
{sunday_open_hours: undefined, sunday_open_mins: undefined}
```

Comment: The data request is async, so `customer_data` is undefined when initializing state. You can instead have a `useEffect` that updates state once the data is available.

Comment: @JBallin, what makes you assert that? There's nothing related to any request in the question. On the contrary, the claim is the data is already there: *"/// returns 08:00:00"* (I'm guessing that's a string).

Comment: @Andrew, the code you posted cannot be used to reproduce the described behavior. Which means the source/reason for it has not yet been included. This makes the question, in its current form, unanswerable, therefore *off-topic*.

Comment: @tao title says fetching data from db, this would be async. Also the optional chaining communicates this. The console is displaying the value of a pointer, which updates over time - initially it would actually show undefined and then after the data is fetched show the string.

Comment: A fine eye for detail, you've got, @JB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe because it takes time to load the data so in this case you need to wait/watch for a change of the retrieved data and update the state according to it. Like this in short

```
export default function App() {
  const [accountInfo, setAccountInfo] = useState({}) 
  useEffect(() => {
    if (customer_data)
    setAccountInfo({ "sunday_open_hours": customer_data?.sunday_open.split(":")[0], 
  "sunday_open_mins" : customer_data?.sunday_open.split(":")[1]});
  },[customer_data])
  console.log(accountInfo)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the value is undefined when you initialize state. Instead you should update state once the value is defined, in a useEffect.

```
const App = () => {
  const [accountInfo, setAccountInfo] = useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData().then((data) => {
      const [sunday_open_hours, sunday_open_mins, sunday_open_secs] =
        data.listCustomers[0].sunday_open.split(":");
      setAccountInfo({ sunday_open_hours, sunday_open_mins });
    });
  }, []);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide a working example or how you are using that at your component?

Also, I suppose that this `customer_data` value is coming from a request. I'm not fully certain but it seems that the `console.log()` call is dispatched before the value is fully fetched, the `useState()` call works directly at that moment and after some time when the `console.log()` starts to execute, the screen get the reference that is already fetched (I'm supposing **a lot of things** here)

But, you should be able to use something like this and update the state after the fetch:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [accountInfo, setAccountInfo] = useState();
  const customer_data = fetchCustomersData();

  useEffect(() => {
    setAccountInfo(customer_data?.sunday_open)
  }, [setAccountInfo, customer_data]);

  const [hours, mins] = accountInfo?.split(":");

  return (
    <p>
      {hours || "00"}:{mins || "00"}
    </p>
  )
```

Another thing you could think of is: the `state` can be something simple and other variables can depend on it. If the state change, those variables should also change.

Hope this helps you!